# Keras LSTM Poor Performance

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to build a word prediction system. I have made a lookup table of all unique words and i have converted the words to integers.I have converted each phrase into a time series format. I am feeding this list padded with zero to the lstm network.

```
inp = pickle.load(open("input.pkl", "rb"))
out = pickle.load(open("output.pkl", "rb"))

inp=np.array(inp,dtype=int)
out=np.array(out,dtype=int)
a=inp.shape
a=(a[1],a[2])

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=a,return_sequences=True,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=a,return_sequences=True,activation='relu',
go_backwards=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=a,return_sequences=True,activation='relu',
go_backwards=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(inp,out,epochs=1000,batch_size=1000,verbose=2,
validation_split=0.25)
model.save('num1.h5')
```

These are the shape of inp and out and the first and second values of inp and out

```
(249368L, 1L, 10L)      #Shape of inp
(249368L, 1L, 1L)       #Shape of out
[[-1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]    #inp[0]
[[1531]]                             #out[0]
[[  -1 1531    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]]         #inp[1]
[[1801]]                                                      #out[1]
```

After the last epoch, this is the accuracy and loss

```
7s - loss: 325231.6975 - acc: 8.0203e-05 - val_loss: 325280.0941 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

I've tried changing the activation functions to sigmoid and tanh, set back propagation to False,tried adam, adagrad optimizer, altered the number of hidden layers in the network. Also i tried adding softmax to the last layer (I removed it since it was causing Vanishing Gradient Problem). Is the problem with the way i am feeding the data to the network or is it something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by making a lookup table of all unique letters than using a lookup table of unique words. Then i predict the next character until the integer corresponding to space is predicted. Thus predicting the next word or completing the current word.